# Vertical Stepper Design xcode11

Tags: xcode, autolayout, storyboard, custom-view, stepper

How to create vertical swappable steppers in storyboard ios.Please suggest solution for designing vertical stepper like in below image.  [image]

Comment: I would start with a vertical slider and customize the empty/filled track.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at ways to create a custom `UISlider` control?